# Intelli-sense not working in VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am unable to get intelli-sense in the editor. I have followed the link below https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/runtimes/nodejs

I have the typings for express, node and other libs.

Works for things that are available at the global level in node (ex. process) but anything else that I require like http or express, intelli-sense doesnt show up.

jsconfig.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=759670
// for the documentation about the jsconfig.json format
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "jspm_packages",
    "tmp",
    "temp"
]
```

}

Thanks in advance.

-------------Update----------------

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,        
    "sourceMap": true
},
"exclude": [
    "node_modules"        
]
}
```

---------Update----------------
using template you suggested, it was missing typings file which I installed, even then I am not getting intellisense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a tsconfig.json file for typescript projects. This will tell the IDE that the project root and its sub-directories are all the same typescript project!

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Comment: Updated, I had a tsconfig.json

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar Take a look at this typescript+nodejs boilerplate: https://github.com/dandevs/NodeTS-Boilerplate/tree/web

Comment: Nope, I am afraid.

Comment: My imports were require style, changing to ES6 got it to work.